# Copying a folder on Windows Server 2008 gives "Error 0x80070057: The parameter is incorrect."

Tags: windows-server-2008

I'm using remote desktop into a Windows Server 2008 machine.  On that machine I use a shared drive on the local network for some development.  I can use those files just fine in Visual Studio, but occasionally when I try to make a copy of the folder (copy & paste), it fails with this error:

Error 0x80070057: The parameter is incorrect.

This is currently happening on one of the files in the .svn folder in this particular folder.  This has happened before, and that time it magically went away.

I can't seem to find much about this on google that applies to my problem.  I simply want to make a copy of this folder.  Any ideas?

Comment: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/0x80070057-error-when-copying-files/cbb592f6-1e50-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5 suggests a possible cause is destination file path name is too long

Comment: @DavidPostill - It's been a *long* time, but I do think it was a case of too-long filenames (ie. too many subfolders).  If you don't mind, please add your comment as an answer and I'll vote it in.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Source [0x80070057 Error when copying files](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/0x80070057-error-when-copying-files/cbb592f6-1e50-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5)

The above article provides several troubleshooting steps.

In addition:

> In my case, I got this error when the path was too long in the destination.   I shortened the name of some of the parent folders, and this error went away, and I could copy the file to its intended destination.

This was confirmed as the cause (and solution) by 3 people who had the same error.